# Attempting to print with multiple inputs, and there are not enough inputted

Tags: python, input

I have written a code that prints out a wall of text that includes variables, once I get the variables to enter correctly the code will work correctly. I am attempting to input multiple variables in one line in python idle. I am using the split function to do so, and it only ever detects one input.

I have attempted to input this multiple times:
10.2.1 1 ACT10p2_Task1_TEAM4D_Template.py 10/30/2019 Caleb.Kunz N/A 4D Header.Code

```
activity, task, file, date, name, section, team, description = input("Type Activity, Task, File, Date, Name, Section, Team, Description ").split(),
print(" # Activity {0} Task {1}\n".format(activity, task),
"# File:  {0}\n".format(file),
"# Date:    {0}\n".format(date),
"# By:       {0}\n".format(name),
"# Section: {0}\n".format(section),
"# Team:    {0}\n".format(team),
"# \n",
"# ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE\n",
"# {0}\n".format(name),
"# \n",
"# The electronic signature above indicates the script\n",
"# submitted for evaluation is my individual work, and I\n",
"# have a general understanding of all aspects of its\n",
"# development and execution.\n",
"# \n",
"# Description: {0}\n".format(description))
```

I expect the output to be a wall of text that uses the inputs to print the wall with the inputs in the correct spots. It instead says it did not receive enough inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing comma at the end of `split()`, that would make the whole statement a tuple. Remove the comma and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you want split by comma:

```
activity, task, file, date, name, section, team, description = input(
        "Type Activity, Task, File, Date, Name, Section, Team, Description ").split(',')
print(" # Activity {0} Task {1}\n".format(activity, task),
"# File:  {0}\n".format(file),
"# Date:    {0}\n".format(date),
"# By:       {0}\n".format(name),
"# Section: {0}\n".format(section),
"# Team:    {0}\n".format(team),
"# \n",
"# ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE\n",
"# {0}\n".format(name),
"# \n",
"# The electronic signature above indicates the script\n",
"# submitted for evaluation is my individual work, and I\n",
"# have a general understanding of all aspects of its\n",
"# development and execution.\n",
"# \n",
"# Description: {0}\n".format(description))
```

test:  test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8

```
Type Activity, Task, File, Date, Name, Section, Team, Description test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8
 # Activity test1 Task test2
 # File:  test3
 # Date:    test4
 # By:       test5
 # Section: test6
 # Team:    test7
 # 
 # ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE
 # test5
 # 
 # The electronic signature above indicates the script
 # submitted for evaluation is my individual work, and I
 # have a general understanding of all aspects of its
 # development and execution.
 # 
 # Description: test8
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting 8 variables to your `input` line. If you type all of the variables this is your output:

```
Type Activity, Task, File, Date, Name, Section, Team, Description activity, task, file, date, name, section, team, description
 # Activity activity, Task task,
 # File:  File, # Date:    date, # By:       name,
 # Section: section,
 # Team:    team,
 #
 # ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE
 # name,
 #
 # The electronic signature above indicates the script
 # submitted for evaluation is my individual work, and I
 # have a general understanding of all aspects of its
 # development and execution.
 #
 # Description: description
```

You should consider using a class or function to set attributes.